# How do you prepend space in a string where Upper Case letter comes or where a space really needed

Tags: sql-server

How do you prepends space in a string where Upper Case letter comes or where a space really needed.

The Sample code is:

```
DECLARE @teams TABLE (Team NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @teams
SELECT 'TataConsultencyServices'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TataConsultencyCompany'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CompanyHumanResource'
```

Expected Result

```
Tata Consultency Services
Tata Consultency Company
Company Human Resource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set based solution:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100);
SET @s = 'CompanyHumanResources';

DECLARE @Idx INT = 1;
WITH CteRecursive
AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS Idx, 
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @s) AS String
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  src.Idx + src.IsUpper + 1,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200),
                CASE WHEN src.IsUpper = 1 THEN STUFF(src.String, src.Idx+1, 0, ' ') ELSE src.String END
            )
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  rec.*,
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(rec.String, rec.Idx, 1) <> ' ' AND SUBSTRING(rec.String, rec.Idx+1, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' AND SUBSTRING(rec.String, rec.Idx+1, 1) COLLATE Romanian_CS_AS = UPPER(SUBSTRING(rec.String, rec.Idx+1, 1)) COLLATE Romanian_CS_AS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsUpper
        FROM    CteRecursive rec
        WHERE   rec.Idx + 1 <= LEN(rec.String)
    ) src
)
SELECT  TOP(1) x.String
FROM    CteRecursive x
ORDER BY x.Idx DESC;
```

Results:

```
String
-----------------------
Company Human Resources
```

Comment: You should replace my collation (`Romanian_CS_AS`) with your **case sensitive** (`..._CS_...`) collation.

Comment: Great but i have to say this that i cant do this query logic by my own so i am searching the new simple logic will post it if i will get it

Comment: But this wont work for parameters like 'TCSolutions' it will return a result like T C Solutions which is actually not required

Comment: This is the indented behavior. There is not such requirement within your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may surely get some help from [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/case-sensitive-sql-split-function.aspx):-

```
CREATE FUNCTION CaseSensitiveSQLSplitFunction
(
 @str nvarchar(max)
)
returns @t table (val nvarchar(max))
as
begin

declare @i int, @j int
select @i = 1, @j = len(@str)

declare @w nvarchar(max)

while @i <= @j
begin
 if substring(@str,@i,1) = UPPER(substring(@str,@i,1)) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
 begin
  if @w is not null
   insert into @t (val) select @w
  set @w = substring(@str,@i,1)
 end
 else
  set @w = @w + substring(@str,@i,1)
 set @i = @i + 1
end
if @w is not null
 insert into @t (val) select @w

return

end
```

Taking the sample as:-

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = N'ThisIsATest'
select * from dbo.CaseSensitiveSQLSplitFunction(@str)
set @str = N'ThisIsASqlServerCaseSensitiveSplitStringFunction'
select * from dbo.CaseSensitiveSQLSplitFunction(@str)
```

[image]

It is now possible to sql concatenate string values in a way from rows to single column value.
We can just use any of the sql concatenation function.

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = N'ThisIsATest'
SELECT LTRIM(STUFF((
  SELECT ' ' + val FROM dbo.CaseSensitiveSQLSplitFunction(@str) FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')) string

set @str = N'ThisIsASqlServerCaseSensitiveSplitStringFunction'
SELECT LTRIM(STUFF((
  SELECT ' ' + val FROM dbo.CaseSensitiveSQLSplitFunction(@str) FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')) string
```

[image]

Comment: thanks buddy that was a help to understand more about case sensitive things .

Answer (score 0):

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
              UPDATE @teams
              SET TeamName = STUFF(TeamName, patindex('%[a-z,.][A-Z]%', TeamName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) + 1,0,' ')
              WHERE patindex('%[a-z,.][A-Z]%', TeamName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) > 0

```
          IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK
```

END

UPDATE @teams
SET TeamName = STUFF(TeamName, patindex('%[A-Z][a-z]%', RIGHT(TeamName,LEN(TeamName) -1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) +1 ,0,' ')
WHERE patindex('%[A-Z][a-z]%', TeamName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) > 0